# What is the name of this connector for my fridge's wooden panel?

Tags: refrigerator, kitchens

I recently snapped off the wooden panel on my fridge/freezer. It is a tall fridge freezer with a separate door for each component. The doors are wooden panels that are attached to the metal doors using plastic connectors.

Recently I snapped the connector on my fridge door, this is the bit screwed in to the metal door (as opposed to to the bit screwed on to the wooden panel) so the panel is now loose from the door.

The panel has not completely fallen off, it is connected just fine on one side with the hinge, just when I open my 'fridge' I am greeted with the metal fridge door.

I am having trouble figuring out what the name of this thing is and where to buy a replacement, it looks like this:

[image]

Two philips head screws connect it to the metal door and another piece of plastic on the wooden panel hooks over the two broken pieces to keep the door and panel connected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think a photo would help.

Comment: what is the make and model of your fridge?

Comment: Can you completely remove one of the connectors (the complete assembly)? If yes, do so & take it to a specialist kitchen shop, they should either be able to sell you the replacement part(s) or point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bracket or a flange to me, check the parts browser [here](http://www.repairclinic.com/Refrigerator-Parts), you might get something close.

Answer (score 1):

They are called Refridgerator panel clips. The design will vary widely with the make and model of the fridge, and they usually need to be purchased from the manufacturer.